# If post decrement have higher precedence than pre increment in JAVA then why does the following code output as 22.0 and not as 20.0 .?

Tags: java, increment, operator-keyword, operator-precedence, decrement

According to precedence rule first `quantity--` should be evaluated which should evaluate to `10` then `++quantity` should be evaluated which should evaluate to `10` then addition performed and result should be `20.0`.

```
    int quantity = 10;
    double total = ++quantity + quantity--;
    System.out.println("total is: - " + total);
```

Comment: That is simply not correct, and operators are evaluated left to right. Pre-increment changes 10 to 11, and post decrement does not take effect until the next line. So `11 + 11` which is `22`. Then (on the next line) `quantity` is 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precedence rules tell you how expressions are parsed. Post decrement having higher precedence means that `++quantity + quantity--` must be parsed as

```
((++quantity) + (quantity--))
```

And not for example as the following which doesn't even make sense

```
((++quantity) + quantity)--
```

The *evaluation order* is unaffected. The expression is still evaluated left to right. That is, left branch of the + before the right branch. That means `++quantity` must be evaluated before `quantity--`.

Comment: By this logic, it would essentially bring the same parsed result when post and pre increment/decrement have the same precedence. Am i right?